# Let $M_i, i \in I$, be R-modules. Show that the (external) direct product $\prod_I M_i$ satisfies the following universal property

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M_i, i \in I$, be R-modules. Show that the (external) direct product $\prod_I M_i$ satisfies the following universal property relative to the R-homomorphisms $\pi_j:\prod_I{M_i} \to Mj$ defined by $\{m_i\}_I \to m_j$ for all $j \in I$: Given an R-module $M$ and R-homomorphisms $g_j : M \to M_j$ for all $j \in I$, there exists a unique R-homomorphism $h:M → \prod_I M$ satisfying $g_j =π_j\circ h$ ,for all $j\in I$.

I have no idea how to start on this problem. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: If the question goes like: try to construct such $R$-module homomorphism $h$, can you come up with some ideas? The construction is quite natural in fact

Comment: I'm not really sure how to construct such a map

Comment: How about $h=\prod_{i\in I}g_i$?

Comment: Oh that's right. Do you mean $h(x)=(g_1(x),g_2(x),...,g_j(x),...)_{j\in I}$

Comment: Yes, it is easy to check well-defined and it is a homomorphism, and satisfying the condition

Comment: I see it now. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Abigail Could you post your comments as an answer? If not, it's desirable that you solve your own question davidh. This answer is already concluded but it compute as unanswered.

Comment: @AlgebraicallyClosed I guess it’s better that he writes down the answer:)

Comment: @Abigail I agree with you :)